# I doubt whether this IS to be believed, or ... HAS to be believed

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

I'm only posting this because I was just about to hit "submit" for my answer to ['is to be endorsed' vs. 'has to be endorsed'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10915/is-to-be-endorsed-vs-has-to-be-endorsed?noredirect=1#comment18261_10915) when the question was closed, and I'm not convinced it will ever be re-opened. This is my attempt to rephrase the question, but it's so radically changed I wouldn't edit the original question.

---

*Believed* and *endorsed* are a bit awkward here, so let's consider these closely-related contexts...

> A: John thinks aliens are already living among us. But John has been under the care of mental health professionals for most of his adult life, so I doubt whether his opinion...
>    A1: ...**is** to be trusted.
>    A2: ...**has** to be trusted.
>
> B: John says we must identify and kill the aliens who are living among us. But John has been under the care of mental health professionals for most of his adult life, so I doubt whether his instruction...
>    B1: ...**is** to be followed.
>    B2: ...**has** to be followed.

Is there any rule about whether to use *is* or *has* in the above, and is it the same for both contexts?

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, ***A1*** is idiomatically the most likely form. ***A2*** is grammatical, but wouldn't be common.
In the second case, ***B1*** is extremely unlikely, if not actually *incorrect*. ***B2*** is the normal phrasing.

In *both* cases, a third option ***should be*** is perfectly valid. The reason *has* works better in ***B*** than ***A*** is because the second context explicitly concerns *obligation* (*has* would be pronounced *hass*, as per [this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37742/pronunciation-of-have-in-i-dont-have-to-do-something)).

In short, I think ***is*** would be the normal choice when we're talking about something that's very much an *optional* reaction (that we may or may not *be having right now*). Using ***has*** places more emphasis on whether or not we *will accept a future obligation*.

Comment: Nice post. +1. I understood everything except the part `future obligation`. What does it mean here?

Comment: I meant that *His instruction **is** to be followed* has more of an "immediate" sense (right now, in this current situation, we should do what he says). Although *His instruction **has** to be followed* could be used in exactly the same context, I feel *that* version is more suitable if speaker is actually referring to some *future* situation where we should do what he says. Note that it's perfectly idiomatic to say *His orders **will have to be** followed* for a "future" context, but although syntactically valid, *His orders **will be to be** followed* is so ugly no-one would normally say it.